# Apple Developer Program Enrollment error - "Your enrollment could not be completed"

Tags: apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am trying to create an apple developer account for past 3 weeks. after selecting

"Select your entity type = Individual" and "Terms & Condition = agree"

an error appears saying "Your enrollment could not be completed". I called support several times and mailed several time they all just simply say at this moment you cannot enroll. when I ask for the reason they simply say they don't no. If they don't know who else would no? I am just stuck here. I cannot publish my app due to their error and they are not helping at all. really frustrating.

additional info:

after I click on the agree button

- The browser does a POST to https://developer.apple.com/services-enrollment/submitIndividualEnrollment
- Result of this POST is `406` with below json

  {"responseId":"7d97f000-ab5e-4a26-9cc3-6498dc322f33","resultCode":202000,"resultString":"Your request could not be processed","userString":"Your request could not be processed","creationTimestamp":"2020-06-30T13:04:36Z","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com/services-enrollment/submitIndividualEnrollment","httpCode":406}

Comment: were you able to sort this out ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the help center. Appstore support questions are off-topic here

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue
**Your enrollment in the Apple Developer Program could not be completed at this time.**

I managed to sort it out through getting **Apple Phone Support** (Durind US working hours : Mon-Fri,9:00 AM–7:00 PM CST).

They sent me a couple of mails in which they had a link to upload my **ID Proof**.

Once I uploaded I contacted them in the same way. They got me verified my ID Proof and unlocked my enrollment. Then I did continue to the enrollment payments process

You can also use the mail support. But its a slow process of getting what we need from support

**Contacting Apple Phone Support:-**

1. Login to [Apple Developer Console](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome)
2. Click **Contact US** in left menu
3. In the next page choose **Membership and Account**
4. In the next popup select **Programme Enrolment**
5. Select **Phone** in the Phone or Email
6. Enter your **Phone Number**. They will call in you within a couple of minutes

Comment: Whenever I do that, I see option for `Email` support only. Emailing them is useless. I don't see option for phone support

Comment: How did you solve the phone support issue did you get to contact them via phone? @Asesh

Comment: @manny You cannot contact them via phone, They contacted me after a few months via email and gave me a special link to join Apple Developer program. Not sure what took them so long

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ""Your enrollment could not be completed" and below the text "Your enrollment in the Apple Developer Program could not be completed at this time."

I found out that so many people have this issue and that Apple does not seem to help out, here is just one example: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129762

I tried different browsers and credit cards without any luck. Then I suddenly managed to enroll from my iPhone, via web over CELLULAR, like this:

1. Disable wifi on iPhone
2. Follow through Apples enroll process https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

I cannot go through the process again to verify, but this was the only changed parameter in my strategy. Hope this can help others.